# Given x nodes and certain connections, how do you find the irrelevant connections?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

Suppose you are trying to connect x nodes. There are already a number of connections >= x.

Each connection is a sub ArrayList within 1 of 2 ArrayLists (a and b).

How do you remove the unnecessary connections, such that a and b have the closest amount of connections to each other, and all nodes are connected?

I know that the min number of connections is x-1. I have tried using prim's, but, I'm not exactly sure how to apply it here.

Here are the 2 arraylists:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

I've given them certain values from input

Comment: As I understand it, you are looking for a [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) of a directed unweighted graph. What specifically does "I have tried using prim's to no success" mean? What sort of try? What is success? What does it mean to have no success? Have you written code? What code? The following guide may be helpful: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Why aren't you using a graph data structure?

Comment: how would I create it with what I have? I guess my thought was to make sure the 2 lists are separate

Comment: Since the edges are unweighted, you don't need to use Prim's algorithm to find the MST. BFS or DFS will work. It's hard to say what you need to do since you haven't shared much code.